# Se omite el primer valor de una consulta sql al guardarlo en un array

Tags: php, mysqli

Necesito obtener los últimos 26 registros más altos de la columna id de mi base de datos. El problema está que con el código de abajo, el programa se salta el primer valor que obtiene, es decir, el más alto. Aquí lo que intento es coger los valores de cada columna y almacenarlos cada uno en un array con el mismo índice por cada registro, es decir que el registro 1 tiene sus valores en los índices `[1]` de cada array. He visto que para recuperar datos de una base de datos se usa ese código en varios blogs y vídeos, por eso no entiendo por qué no va.

Es como si la primera fila se omitiera.

PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, status FROM productos ORDER BY border1,id,border2 DESC LIMIT 26";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$x =0;
if ($result->num_rows > $x) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id[$x] = $row["id"];
    $nombre[$x] = $row["nombre"];
    $status[$x] = $row["status"];
    echo $row["id"];
    $x++;
  }
}
```

[image: Mi base de datos]

Comment: Phpmyadmin es la ide por la cual accedes a tu base de datos.. no es tu base de datos... MYSQL es tu base de datos... Ahora una vez que sabemos esto... que? no se entiende que queres hacer para nada.. tampoco hay un ejemplo de que intentaste.. y tampoco hay un ejemplo de la salida...

Comment: La salida son los registros salvo el más reciente, es como si se salta el primer registro. Y eso que cuando hago la consulta directamente desde phpmyadmin me devuelve los últimos 26 registros sin problema.

Comment: Si estas limitando a 26 registros, va a traer 26 registros... No hay concepto de registro mas reciente a menos que ordenes por fecha... Las bases de datos no ordenan registros...

Comment: si, lo que pasa es que, cuando se guarda la información en los arrays, el primer valor que se debería guardar, lo omite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es que omita el primer registro, sino que *lees* el primer registro en la tercera línea de tu código, para leer y procesar los siguiente ya dentro del bucle:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT id, nombre, status FROM productos
  ORDER BY border1,id,border2 DESC LIMIT 26
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  // aquí lees ese primer registro
$x =0;
if ($result->num_rows > $x) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id[$x] = $row["id"];
    $nombre[$x] = $row["nombre"];
    $status[$x] = $row["status"];
    echo $row["id"];
    $x++;
  }
}
```

Elimina esa línea y lo resolverás